Flask-SQLAlchemy's db.session.commit() error
As a beginner, code like:
class Message(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)

And I open Flask Shell,  m = Message(name='L', content='db.test', timestamp='2024-08-14 12:17:30')
However, when I code db.session.commite()
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input.
[SQL: INSERT INTO message (name, content, timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: [{'timestamp': '2024-08-14 12:17:30', 'content': 'db.test', 'name': 'L'}]]


This is my problem,
find error, what should I do

Did you previously create the database with a different column type for the timestamp column? What does the schema look like when you inspect it from the sqlite cli?

I just change 'timestamp' as 'time'
>>> from app import Message
>>> m = Message(name='L', content='like', time='246800') 
>>> m.time
>>> '246800'
>>> db.session.add(m)
>>> db.session.commit()

This right!
I don't know the rationale behind it. Is it a special name?
